# is there a way to identify if ajax call is executing in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can we programatically identify if a ajax call is executing in infinite loop.

Does it return any specific header when such thing happens? Can we identify this situation by headers in the response.

I have a set of ajax call and have taken care of most things, but still suspect that may be in some cases it might trigger infinite ajax call.

> I make a set of ajax calls which are independent HTTP requests. I do certain calulcation of record processed by ajax call1 by sending another ajax call2.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'<%= path1 %>',
    method:"POST",
    dataType: "script",
    data: {
        batch_id:<%= @id%>
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url:'<%= path2 %>',
    method:"POST",
    dataType: "script",
    data: {
        batch_id:<%= @id%>
    }
});
```

Path 2 ajax calls are depended on path 1 ajax response. so if some varibales are not set properly when path1 ajax calls response or exception arise it may trigger unwanted behaviour or infinite ajax calls for path2 which will not understand when it has to stop since path1 ajax calls has ended abruptly.

instead of **timeout** is there a way from headers recived i can identify if a call is going around infinitely, so that i am sure that its not a long running request and that it needs to abort

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you put some of your code so we can judge better...

Comment: you can visually check ... if there's some infinite loop it's 100% because you wrote it, or are using rubbish library :p

Comment: Let your server write to a log/DB when an AJAX call is received. Your server should also get additional information, like sender, etc. Then you can write your own logic to determine odd behavior based on these logs.

Comment: Haresh have updated my question

Comment: I can't see how that could cause an "infinite loop"

Comment: alnitak, i have mentioned that any exception caused during path1 might trigger infinite call for path2.

Comment: so catch your exceptions, then!   I can't advise further without more code (but not too much more!)

Comment: i have also mentioned that i have catched all, but what if some exceptions have been missed, is there a generic way to abort a infinite ajax call

Comment: your terminology is unclear - an "infinite AJAX loop" to me means that the JS code is repeatedly making AJAX calls over and over.  Do you perhaps mean instead that the _server_ side of a single AJAX call gets stuck in some sort of loop ?

Comment: ajax call is made over and over again and server is returing same resposne and the exit condition will never be satisfied, is there a way to identify such requests programatically

Comment: The code example you provide miss the connection between the 2 ajax calls. Without this clue we could not help you.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be to call second ajax only and only if the first one succeeded.

```
$.ajax({ url: path1,data: data }).done(function Ajax1Succeeeded() {
   console.log("First done");

   $.ajax({ url: path2, data: data }).done(function Ajax2Succeeeded() {
      console.log("Both done"); 
   })
}).fail(function Ajax1Error(){
   console.log("First resulted in error");
});
```

EDIT: If your http requests are independent you could use [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
var ajax1 = $.ajax({url: path1});
var ajax2 = $.ajax({url: path2});

Promise.all([ajax1, ajax2]).then(function(response1, response2){
    console.log("Both ajax call were successful");
}, function(){
    console.log("There was an error");
});
```

Comment: my ajax calls are independent and cant wait for sucess of first one. I have updated my question

Comment: @opensource-ios your edited question suggests otherwise - that "ajax2" is performing calculations on the results of "ajax1"

Comment: yes, that is correct. ajax2 and ajax1 are issued simultaneosuly and ajax2 displays certain counts on basis of ajax1

Comment: that makes them _dependent_, not _independent_, and this answer correct.

Comment: See my update If your requests are really independent.

Comment: so, how does promise solve the issue do identify infinite ajax call?

Comment: @opensource-ios we can't answer that because you _still_ haven't shown how your code would ever enter a "loop"

Comment: Using promise, if your requests are really independent, you can easily call function when both requests are done. Without promise you would have either keep cheking in loop/setTimeout or use some flags to check in `done` functions of both requests whether the other request is done and then call your function.

Comment: I'd avoid `Promise.all` (since it requires ES6 or additional libraries) when jQuery's `$.when` provides the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
$.when( $.ajax( "firstajax" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
// append data or what ever and then  
//second ajax
});
```

the general rule is that the second ajax call should be done when the first one is finished. You can do it like this or simply add the second ajax call in the success method of your first one.

Comment: That `$.when()` call when given a single parameter is completely redundant

Answer (score -1):

if your ajax call 2 totally depends on ajax call 1's success than you can execute your 2'nd ajax call only on success of 1'st ajax call success. use success method :

```
$.ajax({
url:'<%= path1 %>',
method:"POST",
dataType: "script",
data: {
    batch_id:<%= @id%>
}
success : function (res){
          secondAjax();  // call a function on success
}
});



 function secondAjax(){
     $.ajax({
      url:'<%= path2 %>',
      method:"POST",
      dataType: "script",
      data: {
        batch_id:<%= @id%>
      }
      success : function(res){
         alert('both ajax called successfully.');
      }
     });
 }
```

Comment: my ajax calls are issues independently

Comment: By modern jQuery standards (i.e. those that have existed since 2011) that's not a good way of composing AJAX calls.